# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : how to add versioning?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm creating a new ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. In my previous projects with .NET 6 or .NET 7, I can use:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});
```

Now, the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer` is deprecated and I replaced it with the new one `Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer` but there is no extension for `AddVersionedApiExplorer`.

[image]

In the configuration for Swagger, I have the following code:

```
public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
{
    private readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider _provider;

    public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        foreach (var description in _provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc(
                description.GroupName,
                CreateVersionInfo(description));
        }
    }

    public void Configure(string name, SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        Configure(options);
    }

    private static OpenApiInfo CreateVersionInfo(
        ApiVersionDescription description)
    {
        var info = new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = "Test API",
            Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
            Description = "This is a test API.",
        };

        if (description.IsDeprecated)
        {
            info.Description += " This API version has been deprecated.";
        }

        return info;
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I get this error

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Asp.Versioning.ApiExplorer.IApiVersionDescriptionProvider' while attempting to activate 'Middletier.Api.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigureSwaggerOptions'.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`AddApiVersioning` works a bit different (it returns `IApiVersioningBuilder`). Install `Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer` which will allow to call [`AddApiExplorer`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/8b0a70dfcc10a4d84e1661809e9b91307f04be72/src/AspNetCore/WebApi/src/Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer/DependencyInjection/IApiVersioningBuilderExtensions.cs#L26) on `IApiVersioningBuilder` returned by `AddApiVersioning`:

```
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    })
    .AddApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });
```

See the [Quick Start](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/New-Services-Quick-Start#aspnet-core-with-mvc-core), [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/main/examples/AspNetCore/WebApi/BasicExample) and this question - [ApiVersion attribute not working in .NET 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77502548/2501279)

Answer (score 3):

In .NET8 I'm using very simple steps to achieve similar result.

First I'm adding the API explorer.

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

Then I'm using IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider or IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider for the swagger configs.
I'm using the latest version(8.0.0 atm) of Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer